# Evaluate integral $\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2+x-1}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2+x-1}}\mathrm dx$$

I tried to factorize $x^2+x-1$ and use a substitution $$u=\sqrt{\frac{a(x-\alpha)}{x-\beta}}$$

What substitution to use in this integral?

Comment: Try the [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) with $$x=\frac{u^2+1}{2u+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2+x-1}}dx$$
Euler Substitution:

Let $x=\frac{u^2+1}{2u+1}$, $$I=2\int \frac{(2u+1)^2}{(u^2+1)^3}du$$
Partial fraction get $I=2\int \frac{4u-3}{(u^2+1)^3}du+8\int\frac{1}{(u^2+1)^2}du$

Answer (score 0):

With $h(x)= \sqrt{x^2+x-1}$, it is straightforward to verify
$$\left(\frac {h(x)}{2x^2}+ \frac {3h(x)}{4x}\right)’= \frac1{x^3 h(x)}-\frac7{8x h(x)}
$$
and integrate both sides to reduce the integral

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2+x-1}} dx\\
= & \int \frac{1}{x^3h(x)}dx
=\left( \frac {1}{2x^2}+ \frac {3}{4x} \right)h(x) 
+\frac78\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2+x-1}}dx\\
=&\ \left( \frac {1}{2x^2}+ \frac {3}{4x} \right) \sqrt{x^2+x-1}+\frac78\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac12x-1}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}}
\end{align}
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656680/686284) for evaluating the reduced integral $ \int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2+x-1}}$.