# How do I solve $-\int \frac{dy}{y(ay^2+by+c)^{1/2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral which I am trying to solve, but I am unsure of how to proceed! Any help is much appreciated!

\begin{equation}
-\int \frac{dy}{y(ay^2+by+c)^{1/2}}
\end{equation}

My strategy is to complete the square on the denominator and find a viable trig substitution. I am currently at stage of having completed the square, and performed a substitution.
\begin{equation}
-\int \frac{du}{\bigg(u-\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)\bigg(u^2+ \frac c a -\frac 1 4 \bigg(\frac ba \bigg)^2\bigg)^{\frac 12}}
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
u=y + \left(\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)
\end{equation}

The result should take the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-c}} \cos ^{-1}\frac{by +2c}{y\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}
\end{equation}
Where $c<0$.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Probably the reason someone voted to close the question is that you present something that looks as if it could be a homework problem without anything about where you got stuck.

Comment: Apologies, I will pop my attempt in! I am trying to work from this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integral

Comment: WA says $$\frac{\log (y)-\log \left(2 \sqrt{c} \sqrt{y (a y+b)+c}+b y+2 c\right)}{\sqrt{c}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think you forgot to take the $-$ into account when typing it onto WA.
$$\mathbf{\color{red}{-}}\int \frac{dy}{y(ay^2+by+c)^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With
> Euler-sub$\ds{\ldots\ \root{ay^{2} + by + c} = \root{a}y + t}$:

\begin{align}
& \int{\dd y \over y\root{ay^{2} + by + c}} =
\int{2\,\dd t \over t^{2} - c} =
{1 \over \root{c}}\int\pars{%
{1 \over t - \root{c}} - {1 \over t + \root{c}}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over \root{c}}\,\ln\pars{t - \root{c} \over t + \root{c}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over \root{c}}\,\ln\pars{\root{ay^{2} + by + c} - \root{a}y - \root{c} \over \root{ay^{2} + by + c} - \root{a}y + \root{c}} +
\pars{~\mbox{a}\ constant~}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

**Hint on the general method:**

This is an example of an *abelian integral*, i.e. an integral of the form
$$\int R(y,u)\,\mathrm dy,\qquad\text{where $u$ and $y$ are linked by a polynomial relation}\enspace p(y,u)=0 $$
Here, setting $u=\sqrt{ay^2+by+c}$, we obtain the quadratic relation $\;ay^2-u^2+by+c=0$.

If $a\ne 0$, this integral can be calculated by substitution with the following steps:

- First  write the quadratic polynomial $f(y)=ay^2+by+c\;$ in canonical form:
  $$ay^2+by+c=a\biggl[\Bigl(y+\frac b{2a}\Bigr)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}\biggr].$$
  Set $\;t=y+\smash[t]{\dfrac b{2a}}$ and, as usual $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.
- Depending on the signs of $a$ and  $\Delta$, the square root takes one of the forms:
  $$\sqrt{ay^2+by+c}=\begin{cases}
  \lvert a\rvert\sqrt{t^2 -D^2}&\bigl(D=\sqrt{\lvert\Delta\rvert}\bigr)\\[1ex]
  \lvert a\rvert\sqrt{t^2 +D^2}\\[1ex]
  \lvert a\rvert\sqrt{D^2-t^2}
  \end{cases}$$
- The trick is now to find a substitution that eliminates the square root:
- For $\sqrt{t^2 -D^2}$, one can set $\;t=D\cosh\theta$ $\;(\theta\ge 0)$.
- For $\sqrt{t^2 +D^2}$, one can set $\;t=D\sinh\theta$, or $\;t=D\tan\theta$ $\;(-\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac\pi2)$.
- For $\sqrt{D^2 -t^2}$, one can set $\;t=D\sin\theta$ $\;(-\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac\pi2)$, or $\;t=D\tanh\theta$.

These substitutions turn  the integral into the integral of a `rational function` of `trigonometric` or `hyperbolic` functions, which in turn can be changed into an integral of a `rational function` by a suitable second substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $a, c\gt0, 4ac-b^2>0$.

Switching to $x$ as a variable because I'm used to it and denoting the integral with $I$.

First complete the square:

$$ -I=\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{(\sqrt ax+\frac{b}{2\sqrt a})^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}}}=2\sqrt a\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2}}$$

Now perform substitution $u=2ax+b$ and you get

$$2\sqrt a\int\frac{du}{(u-b)\sqrt{u^2+4ac-b^2}}$$

Now substitution $u=\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\sinh (v)$ and simplifying you get 
$$2\sqrt a\int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\sinh(v)-b}$$

Now half-angle hyperbolic substitution $w=\tanh(\frac v2)$ yields
$$2\sqrt a\int\frac{2\,dw}{bw^2+2\sqrt{(4ac-b^2)}w-b}$$

Now factor the denominator (a bit tedious) and perform PFD, and you'll get a few easy integrals, undo the substitutions and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Presented below is the most general result. Consider
$$g(y)= \frac{c+\frac b2 y}{\sqrt{ay^2+by+c}}\implies
g’(y)=\frac{g^2(y)-c}{y \sqrt{ay^2+by+c}}$$
which lead to
\begin{align}
& \int \frac1{y \sqrt{ay^2+by+c}}dy \\
=& \int \frac{g’(y)}{g^2(y)-c}\ dy
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-c}}\tan^{-1}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{-c}}, &c<0\\
-\frac1{g(y)},&c=0\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}\ln |\frac{g(y)-\sqrt c}{g(y)+\sqrt c}|, &c>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}